# How to handle multiple redirection in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to open a page after a form post inside evaluate. There are 2 redirections after form post which can be any number and then I find a final page.

I tried to handled it by putting below (2 times for 2 redirections) after evaluate in which form post happened.

```
await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil':'domcontentloaded'});
await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil':'domcontentloaded'});
```

The above worked properly but I have to handle the situations when any number of redirections can happen.

I won't have any specific selector on DOM as page might be different many times.

- Puppeteer version: 1.4.0
- Platform / OS version: Linux
- URLs (if applicable): NA
- Node.js version: 8.10.0

The below is part of code which I am using:

```
const formPost = await page.evaluate(a => {

    var form = formBuilder("payment_post", "post", acsUrl);                
    for (var i in a) {
        form.add(i, i, 'hidden', a[i]);
    }
    form.generate("pareqFormContainer");
    form.submit();
    return document.querySelector('#pareqFormContainer').innerHTML;

}, jsonData)
.then(function () {
    logger.info("form submitted with pareq and MD for txnId : " + jsonData.txnId)
});               

await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded', 'timeout' : waitTimeOut}); 
await page.waitForNavigation({'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded', 'timeout' : waitTimeOut});
```

Comment: If there can be any number of redirects and no specific selector at the end then how would you (as a human) understand that you've reached the page you need?

Comment: Simply by realizing that there are no more redirections going on, ie. network is idling. There is related feature request: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/902